# Finding how "spreaded" a point cloud in 3D

Tags: geometry, 3d

I don't know the proper term for "spreaded" but what I want to find is, a value that indicates how far is an average point from the centroid.

I think this is standard deviation of the point set, but I need metrics.

For instance, consider the figures:

[image]

Here, blue points are centroids and black points are the points in the cloud.
In both cases, standard deviation is the same, but the first cloud is more "spreaded".

If a spread factor $\alpha$ were to be given, how would you compute $\alpha$ given the 3D coordinates of the points?

Comment: The standard deviation of what? Distance from the centroid? If so, the standard deviation of the first set is much more than the standard deviation of the second set.

Comment: @TonyK Standard deviation of the points.

Comment: It seems to me that you must have misunderstood what standard deviation means! Please update your post with the definition that you are using: given $n$ points $(x_i,y_i)$, how do you calculate the "standard deviation of the points", as you call it?

Comment: @TonyK But I don't want to compute the st.dev. I want to compute how spreaded are the points or how cumulated they are. Sorry but I don't know the terminology

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand your gripe with standard deviation.  However, here's something that should work:

Let $\{(x_i,y_i,z_i): i = 1,\dots n\}$ be a collection of points.  Let 
$(x,y,z) = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ be the centroid.  We can take 
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ((x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2 + (z-z_i)^2)}{n}
$$
$\sigma = \sqrt{\sigma^2}$ gives you the standard deviation in Euclidean distance of all points from the centroid, which should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Here, $\sigma^2$ is essentially the sum of variances in each dimension (x,y,z) right?

Comment: @makis yes, exactly.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have two 2D clouds (scatter plots) and I want to estimate the ratio of spread. So I used your solution but I get a very small ratio value for a case where, visually, the spread ratio should be large. see here: https://pasteboard.co/IWksrRU.png Any tip?

Comment: @makis however big you think that the ratio should be, this formula should be fine for comparing the two data clouds

Comment: or maybe this is more appropriate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13274/181233 ?

Comment: @makis my method is exactly what is written there, only I have chosen the $L_2$ norm.  If you like, you could try different norms.  Unless you have something in particular that you're looking for, I would stick to the $L_2$ norm which is the "default"

Comment: thanks . cheers !